# How do you insert data from one form into a listbox in another form while checking for unique values?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have two forms, HomeForm and AddForm. AddForm has five text boxes, registrationNumber, carMake, carModel, carYear, and carHireCost. I have created code that sends the information to the list box as expected. This looks like this:

```
        HomeForm f1 = (HomeForm)Application.OpenForms["HomeForm"];
            f1.UpdateListBox(registrationNumber.Text + "     " + carMake.Text + "     " + carModel.Text + "     " + carYear.Text + "     " + carHireCost.Text);
            this.Hide();
```

I want to be able to check if the registration number already exists. If it does, it will throw an error and not update the list box. If it is a unique registration number, it will add it to the list, as well as the other details. How might I write a statement that checks the uniqueness before trying to update the list?

For example:

```
if ("check registration exists = does exist"){
 MessageBox.Show("Registration Number already exists.", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}else{
  HomeForm f1 = (HomeForm)Application.OpenForms["HomeForm"];
            f1.UpdateListBox(registrationNumber.Text + "     " + carMake.Text + "     " + carModel.Text + "     " + carYear.Text + "     " + carHireCost.Text);
            this.Hide();
}
```

**Edit**
I have a method in my home form that updates the listbox, where vehicleList is the name of the listbox. It looks like this:

```
  public void UpdateListBox(string lstValue)
        {
            vehicleList.Items.Add(lstValue);
        }
```

Comment: This can be done in a multitude of ways. You could have a method in your HomeForm that can check if the listbox has the passed in registration number, you could have a third class that adds the registration number to a collection which you can check against, etc.

Comment: What is the code `f1.UpdateListBox` doing? You should show this code. You should [edit] your question to provide more details in how the code is currently adding items to the `ListBox.`

Comment: Use instance of the forms.  See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: I have updated my question with the method in the home form that updates the listbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to check if the “registration number” is already in the list, then, as it currently stands, you have two choices…

1. Parse out the registration number from the passed in variable `lstValue`, then loop through each list item and see if the item contains the registration number.

Or

2. Pass in the registration number as a separate variable. Then loop through each item in the list to see if the item contains the registration number.

Using the second approach may look something like…

```
public void UpdateListBox(string regNumber, string lstValue) {
  foreach (string item in vehicleList.Items) {
    if (item.Contains(regNumber)) {
      MessageBox.Show("Registration number: " + regNumber + " already exist in the list! Item not added!");
      return;
    }
  }
  vehicleList.Items.Add(regNumber + "      " + lstValue);
}
```

Comment: Ill give this a try

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `Contains` method on the `ListBox`'s `Items` collection to check if the `ListBox` already contains the entry.

```
public void UpdateListBox(string lstValue)
{
    if(vehicleList.Items.Contains(lstValue)
    {
        return; // already in list, do not add again
    }
    vehicleList.Items.Add(lstValue);
}
```